# Правильная настройка nginx и Django для https

Tags: django, nginx, http, https

у меня есть настройка nginx для https:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $https_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

но вопрос стоит в том, нужно ли добавить в строку proxy_pass http://backend; префикс s к http, или он по другим настройкам сам поймет?

Comment: Если ваш бэкенд принимает запросы по https, то стоит. Если не принимает, то не стоит

Comment: принимает, но правильно ли я оформил это в настройках nginx?